# VBA - Query Table - Getting data from google sheet

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

I have a **function** i mostly found on web, **to get a table from Google Sheets**.

```
Sub GetDataFromGoogle(wsn As String, address As String)
Dim i As Integer
  With Worksheets(wsn)
    With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & address, Destination:=.Range("$A$1"))
        .PreserveFormatting = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    DoEvents
  End With
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Connections.Count
        If ThisWorkbook.Connections.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        ThisWorkbook.Connections.item(i).Delete
    i = i - 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

It seems to work well, but as i develloped my data base, a problem happened.

**I only get the first 100 entries of my google sheet**, then i got a empty line, a strange text on the first next range, and then the line under in position 3 the word `List`

I have no idea of what it is.

Comment: "a strange text" - what does that look like?  Does it correspond to some specific line in your Google sheet?

Comment: It is not in my sheet at all. I have never seen this text before : ``Les cours des actions ne couvrent pas toutes les places boursiÃ¨res et peuvent Ãªtre diffÃ©rÃ©s d'une durÃ©e allant jusqu'Ã  20Â minutes. Les chiffres sont fournis "en l'Ã©tat", Ã  titre d'information uniquement, et non Ã  des fins commerciales ou de conseils. Clause de non-responsabilitÃ©``. It is always the same text.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Sub Uygula()
 Sheets("Veri").Range("A1:D600").ClearContents
 Call GetDataFromGoogle("Veri", "18I8Vddjir3lFvtUorMln4mXlYNsY0KZtBGywVreped4")
End Sub

Sub GetDataFromGoogle(wsn As String, adres As String)
Dim i As Integer
Dim qry As String
Dim myURL As String
    qry = Application.EncodeURL("SELECT A, C, G, B")
    myURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" & adres & "/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=1&tq=" & qry

With Worksheets(wsn)
With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & myURL, Destination:=.Range("$A$1"))
     .Name = "myTable"
     .TextFilePlatform = 65001
     .SaveData = False
     .AdjustColumnWidth = True
     .RefreshPeriod = 0
     .TextFileStartRow = 1
     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
     .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
     .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
     .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
'DoEvents
End With
'For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Connections.Count
'If ThisWorkbook.Connections.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
'ThisWorkbook.Connections.Item(i).Delete
'i = i - 1
'Next i
End Sub
```